# My Screen Recorder built using OpenCV and PyAutoGUI records only one frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, pyautogui

I am building a Screen Recorder in Python using numpy, OpenCV and PyAutoGUI. I have used tkinter for GUI Purposes. The problem with my screen recorder is that it records only one frame when I click on the Record Screen Button and then the screen gets jammed and I can't do anything. Here is my code so far:

```
from tkinter import *
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pyautogui

resolution = (1366,768)
```

Specify video codec:

```
codec = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"XVID")
```

Specify name of Output file:

```
filename = "Recordings.avi"
```

Specify frames rate (we can choose any value and experiment with it):

```
fps = 30.0
```

Creating a `VideoWriter` object:

```
out = cv2.VideoWriter(filename, codec, fps, resolution)

def startRecording():
  
  window.iconify()
  while True:
    img = pyautogui.screenshot()

    # Convert the screenshot to a numpy array
    frame = np.array(img)

    # Convert it from BGR(Blue, Green, Red) to
    # RGB(Red, Green, Blue)
    
    frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

    # Write it to the output file
      out.write(frame)

def stopRecording():
  cv2.destroyAllWindows()
  out.release()
  window.destroy()



window = Tk()
window.title("Screen Recorder")
window.geometry("400x150")
window.config(bg='pink')

recordButton = Button(window,text="Record(F9)",font=("Bell MT",20),width=20,command=startRecording)
recordButton.pack(pady=(10,0))

stopButton = Button(window,text="Stop(F10)",font=("Bell MT",20),width=20,command=stopRecording)
stopButton.pack(pady=(10,0))

mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do a blocking call in a button callback.
As you wrote it `startRecording` will never end and will hence block tkinter mainloop. The recording probably works but your UI becomes unresponsive.

Your best shot would be to schedule the recording (look for the [`after`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-after-method-in-tkinter/) method): record one frame every x millisecond.

Here is a simplified example based on your original code (you need to complete it)

```
continueRecording = True # must be declared before stopRecording 
window = Tk() # must be declared before recordOneFrame

def stopRecording():
    global continueRecording
    continueRecording = False 

def recordOneFrame():
    global continueRecording
    img = pyautogui.screenshot()

    # Convert the screenshot to a numpy array
    frame = np.array(img)

    # Convert it from BGR(Blue, Green, Red) to
    # RGB(Red, Green, Blue)
    
    frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

    # Write it to the output file
    out.write(frame)
    if continueRecording:
        window.after(round(1/25. * 1000),recordOneFrame)
        

def startRecording():
    recordOneFrame()
```

Comment: How can i do it?

Comment: I updated my answer with some code showing the principle.

Comment: Thank you for your answer...Can you please tell me how have you done the calculation?
Basically in this line of code

window.after(round(1/25. * 1000),recordOneFrame)

Comment: @TaylorSwift it is 25 frames per second.

Comment: Is this for a class assignment? Python might not be the first codebase that comes to mind when working with video.